# Mark rows based on there sequence (successive values)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

The task here is to mark rows based on their sequence.

Input:

```
393403  "a" 0   1
393404  "b" 0   1
393404  "b" 2   1
393404  "b" 4   1
393404  "b" 5   1
393404  "c" 12  1
393404  "c" 14  1
393404  "c" 16  2
393404  "c" 21  1
393404  "c" 23  1
393404  "d" 28  1
393404  "d" 30  1
393404  "d" 32  2
393404  "d" 37  1
393404  "d" 39  1
393405  "e" 1   1
393405  "e" 4   1
393405  "e" 6   2
```

I want to extract all rows where the sequence of the last column is 1 | 1 | 2. Also, the first and the second columns must have the same values in that sequence groups.

In this example that would be these rows:

```
393404  "c" 12  1
393404  "c" 14  1
393404  "c" 16  2


393404  "d" 28  1
393404  "d" 30  1
393404  "d" 32  2


393405  "e" 1   1
393405  "e" 4   1
393405  "e" 6   2
```

By mark/extract I mean to update another column with 1/2.

Attempt

My first attempt was to use LAG function, but how can I start with LAG from value 2?

Comment: What do you mean by "*how can I start with LAG from value 2*"?

Comment: as I understand LAG will refer to previous rows in a partition

Answer (score 1):

**This is by no means a complete answer**

Lag/Lead function accepts an "offset" parameter: [Introduction to PostgreSQL LAG() function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/)

I've got [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=df10ee855e449a360eee3ea1c8795128), maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort I appreciate! Will work it out in a loop (cursor)

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with a similar problem the other day, and came across a few ideas. In your case, it looks like you want to capture rows based both on their contents (columns 1 and 2), and the contents of neighboring rows with the same columns 1 & 2. Which makes `LAG()` seem like a good idea.

Reworking a bit of your example here, I've put a `*` in front or rows that match your conditions, and have spelled out the sequence in a column on the right. I also gave the columns made-up names because I'm useless with examples where the columns are simple numbers or "a", "b", etc. It's my thing, I'll deal with it ;-)

```
    batch    team  first  last      series
    393403   "a"       0     1      1

    393404   "b"       0     1      1
    393404   "b"       2     1      1-1
    393404   "b"       4     1      1-1-1
    393404   "b"       5     1      1-1-1-1
*   393404   "c"      12     1      1-1-1-1-1
*   393404   "c"      14     1      1-1-1-1-1-1
*   393404   "c"      16     2      1-1-1-1-1-1-2
    393404   "c"      21     1      1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1
    393404   "c"      23     1      1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1

*   393404   "d"      28     1      1
*   393404   "d"      30     1      1-1
*   393404   "d"      32     2      1-1-2
    393404   "d"      37     1      1-1-2-1

*   393405   "e"       1     1      1
*   393405   "e"       4     1      1-1
*   393405   "e"       6     2      1-1-2
```

The `batch + team` grouping and matching seems pretty ordinary, the tricky bit is the `series`. "Find me rows that contribute to a a `series` that ends in `1-1-2`.

The `first` column doesn't seem to be part of the search, only the output.

This is similar to a problem I'm working. In my case, it's time-series data of events where the series is a set of states. Like "clean", "prep", "qa", and "storage". But your numbers are fundamental the same....I think.

Have you thought of building out the series to make it a searchable condition? Either virtually by grouping by `batch` and `team` and running [string_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in a CTE, or by materializing the series in a denormalized column? If you haven't, look at the standard [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) extension. It provides a ton of functions an operators to do fast (indexable) path searches. That's the direction I'm contemplating, but I don't have my head around the operators enough to write sample code for you. If this idea is at all sound and interesting, hopefully someone else can kick in some more help.

Comment: it would be nice that there is a feature with one u can just join a sequence that you want to search for. Join with your main query, like a shape that you want it to fit into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for taking the time to think and help me with this. Yesterday I've created cursor based solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUBLIC.TABELA4_INSERT(PROCESS_COUNT integer DEFAULT 50) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS $BODY$
declare
    cur refcursor;
    trans_ record;
    what_prev integer = 0;
    raank_prev integer = 0;
    two boolean = false;
    two_id integer = 0;
    three boolean = false;
    three_id integer = 0;
    four boolean = false;
    four_id integer = 0;
BEGIN
open cur FOR
    with bl as
    (
        select tl.blocknumber
        from public.log tl left join
            tabela4 t4 on tl.blocknumber = t4.blocknumber
        where status_transferlogs = B'1' and date_transferlogs_parsed is not null
          and (
            status_swaplogs = B'1' and date_swaplogs_parsed is not null
              or
            status_swaplogs = B'0'
          )
        and tl.blocknumber > 393400
        group by tl.blocknumber
        order by tl.blocknumber
        limit process_count
    ), tl as
    (
        select tl.id, bl.blocknumber, tl.hash, tl.logindex, 1 what
        from public.tansferlogs tl join
            bl on tl.blocknumber = bl.blocknumber left join
            tabela4 t4 on tl.hash = t4.hash
        where t4.blocknumber is null
        group by tl.id, bl.blocknumber, tl.hash, tl.logindex
        union
        select tl.id, bl.blocknumber, tl.hash, tl.logindex, 2
        from public.swaplogs tl join
            bl on tl.blocknumber = bl.blocknumber left join
            tabela4 t4 on tl.hash = t4.hash
        where t4.blocknumber is null
        group by tl.id, bl.blocknumber, tl.hash, tl.logindex
    )
    select id, blocknumber, hash, logindex, what,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           order by blocknumber, hash
        ) raank
    from tl
    order by blocknumber, hash, logindex desc;

truncate table films_recent;

loop

    fetch cur into trans_;
    exit when not found;
    
    INSERT INTO public.films_recent(blocknumber, hash, logindex, what, raank, id)
    VALUES (trans_.blocknumber, trans_.hash, trans_.logindex, trans_.what, trans_.raank, trans_.id);
    
    if raank_prev <> trans_.raank then
        two = false;
        two_id = 0;
        three = false;
        three_id = 0;
        four = false;
        four_id = 0;
        raank_prev = trans_.raank;
    end if;
        
    if trans_.what = 1 then
        if two and three then
            four = true;
            four_id = trans_.id;
        elseif two then
            three = true;
            three_id = trans_.id;
            four = false;
            four_id = 0;    
        end if;
    end if;
    if trans_.what = 2 then
        two = true;
        two_id = trans_.id;
        three = false;
        three_id = 0;
        four = false;
        four_id = 0;    
    
    end if;
    raise notice '%-%-%', two_id, three_id, four_id;
    if two and three and four then
        update films_recent
        set "check" = true
        where id = two_id and what = 2
         or what = 1 and id in (three_id, four_id);
        two = false;
        two_id = 0;
        three = false;
        three_id = 0;
        four = false;
        four_id = 0;        
    end if;
    
    
end loop;

close cur;

commit;

return;

END
$BODY$;
```

This is only a part of it, and I still need to process those records that are in 1-1-2 group.

results:

```
393403  "a" 0   1   1   488594  
393404  "b" 39  1   2   488606  
393404  "b" 37  1   2   488605  
393404  "b" 32  2   2   2669079 true
393404  "b" 30  1   2   488604  true
393404  "b" 28  1   2   488603  true
393404  "c" 23  1   3   488602  
393404  "c" 21  1   3   488601  
393404  "c" 16  2   3   2669078 true
393404  "c" 14  1   3   488600  true
393404  "c" 12  1   3   488599  true
393404  "d" 5   1   4   488598  
393404  "d" 4   1   4   488597  
393404  "d" 2   1   4   488596
```

Note: results are ordered in descending order.